# A function that returns true only if two conditions are met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am designing a game of solitaire,

Basically I want to be able to let the person win if:

1. There is no card on the first pile
2. All the cards are on one of the other piles

In order to do this I want my function to only return true if both these conditions are met I have this so far:

```
def Win(self):

    test1 = 0
    test2 = 0

    if self.t[0].size() == 0:
        test1 = True

    for pile in self.t:
        if pile.size() == self.__CardNo:
            test2 = True

    if test1 == True and test2 == True:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider simplifying `Win()` down to something like:

```
def Win(self):

    if sum(pile.size() for pile in self.t) == self.__CardNo:
        return self.t[0].size() == 0

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is improved with the realisation you can assign the result of comparsions into variables with descriptive names. For example:

```
def has_won(self):
    first_pile_empty = 0 == len(self.piles[0])
    other_piles_full = self.CARD_COUNT == sum(len(pile) for pile in self.piles[1:])
    return first_pile_empty and other_piles_full
```

You'll note I've taken the liberty to make some other style adjustments to your code:

- Renamed `Win()` to `has_won()`.
- Renamed `self.t` to `self.piles`.
- Changed method for counting cards on a pile from `size()` to `__len__()`.
- Renamed `__CardNo` to `CARD_COUNT` (assuming it's a class variable).

You may find there's a better way to determine if the player has won after refactoring other parts of your code, I'd think just checking the top card of each result pile would be enough but this is simple enough logic to tweak later.